# Getting too many errors while trying to contourplot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to contourplot deviations for various combinations of a,b,k,l with the following code.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

```
\[Eta][a_, b_, k_, l_, M_, r_] := 
 1/(a^2 + a^2 l - 
   r^2) (-2 a^2 b k - 2 a^2 b k l - (a^4 k)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) - (
    2 a^4 k l)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) - (a^4 k l^2)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) - (
    2 a^4 k)/r - (4 a^4 k l)/r - (2 a^4 k l^2)/r - (
    2 a^2 b k r)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) - (
    2 a^2 b k l r)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) + (
    4 a^2 k M r)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) + (4 a^2 k l M r)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) -
     a^2 r^2 - b^2 r^2 + 2 b k r^2 - a^2 l r^2 + (
    8 a^2 M^2 r^2)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r)^2 + (
    8 a^2 l M^2 r^2)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r)^2 - (
    a^2 b r^2)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) - (a^2 k r^2)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) - (
    b^2 k r^2)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) - (a^2 b l r^2)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) - (
    a^2 k l r^2)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) - (2 a^2 M r^2)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) + (
    4 b k M r^2)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) - (
    2 a^2 l M r^2)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) - 4 b r^3 + 2 k r^3 - (
    2 a^2 r^3)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) - (2 b^2 r^3)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) - (
    2 a^2 l r^3)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) - 3 r^4 - (
    8 M^2 r^4)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r)^2 - (
    8 M^2 r^4)/((1 + l) (-b + 2 M - 2 r)^2) - (
    8 l M^2 r^4)/((1 + l) (-b + 2 M - 2 r)^2) - (
    6 b r^4)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) + (k r^4)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) - (b^3 r^4)/(
    a^2 (1 + l) (-b + 2 M - 2 r)) + (b^2 k r^4)/(
    a^2 (1 + l) (-b + 2 M - 2 r)) + (4 M r^4)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) + (
    2 b^2 M r^4)/(a^2 (1 + l) (-b + 2 M - 2 r)) - (4 b k M r^4)/(
    a^2 (1 + l) (-b + 2 M - 2 r)) - (4 r^5)/(-b + 2 M - 2 r) - (
    4 b^2 r^5)/(a^2 (1 + l) (-b + 2 M - 2 r)) + (2 b k r^5)/(
    a^2 (1 + l) (-b + 2 M - 2 r)) + (8 b M r^5)/(
    a^2 (1 + l) (-b + 2 M - 2 r)) - (4 k M r^5)/(
    a^2 (1 + l) (-b + 2 M - 2 r)) + (4 M^2 r^6)/(
    a^2 (1 + l)^2 (-b + 2 M - 2 r)^2) + (4 l M^2 r^6)/(
    a^2 (1 + l)^2 (-b + 2 M - 2 r)^2) + (4 M^2 r^6)/(
    a^2 (1 + l) (-b + 2 M - 2 r)^2) - (5 b r^6)/(
    a^2 (1 + l) (-b + 2 M - 2 r)) + (k r^6)/(
    a^2 (1 + l) (-b + 2 M - 2 r)) + (6 M r^6)/(
    a^2 (1 + l) (-b + 2 M - 2 r)) - (2 r^7)/(
    a^2 (1 + l) (-b + 2 M - 2 r)) + 
    1/(a (-b + 2 M - 2 r)^2) 2 Sqrt[1 + l]
      M r^2 \[Sqrt](a^2 (1 + l) M^2 (-4 a^2 + (4 r^2)/(1 + l))^2 - 
        4 a^2 (-b + 2 M - 2 r) (a^4 b + a^4 k + a^2 b^2 k + a^4 b l + 
           a^4 k l + 2 a^4 M - 4 a^2 b k M + 2 a^4 l M + (a^6 k)/
           r^2 + (2 a^6 k l)/r^2 + (a^6 k l^2)/r^2 + (2 a^4 b k)/r + (
           2 a^4 b k l)/r - (4 a^4 k M)/r - (4 a^4 k l M)/r + 
           2 a^4 r + 2 a^2 b^2 r + 2 a^4 l r + 6 a^2 b r^2 - 
           a^2 k r^2 + (b^3 r^2)/(1 + l) - (b^2 k r^2)/(1 + l) - 
           4 a^2 M r^2 - (2 b^2 M r^2)/(1 + l) + (4 b k M r^2)/(
           1 + l) + 4 a^2 r^3 + (4 b^2 r^3)/(1 + l) - (2 b k r^3)/(
           1 + l) - (8 b M r^3)/(1 + l) + (4 k M r^3)/(1 + l) + (
           5 b r^4)/(1 + l) - (k r^4)/(1 + l) - (6 M r^4)/(1 + l) + (
           2 r^5)/(1 + l))) - 
    1/(a^3 Sqrt[1 + l] (-b + 2 M - 2 r)^2)
      2 M r^4 \[Sqrt](a^2 (1 + l) M^2 (-4 a^2 + (4 r^2)/(1 + l))^2 - 
        4 a^2 (-b + 2 M - 2 r) (a^4 b + a^4 k + a^2 b^2 k + a^4 b l + 
           a^4 k l + 2 a^4 M - 4 a^2 b k M + 2 a^4 l M + (a^6 k)/
           r^2 + (2 a^6 k l)/r^2 + (a^6 k l^2)/r^2 + (2 a^4 b k)/r + (
           2 a^4 b k l)/r - (4 a^4 k M)/r - (4 a^4 k l M)/r + 
           2 a^4 r + 2 a^2 b^2 r + 2 a^4 l r + 6 a^2 b r^2 - 
           a^2 k r^2 + (b^3 r^2)/(1 + l) - (b^2 k r^2)/(1 + l) - 
           4 a^2 M r^2 - (2 b^2 M r^2)/(1 + l) + (4 b k M r^2)/(
           1 + l) + 4 a^2 r^3 + (4 b^2 r^3)/(1 + l) - (2 b k r^3)/(
           1 + l) - (8 b M r^3)/(1 + l) + (4 k M r^3)/(1 + l) + (
           5 b r^4)/(1 + l) - (k r^4)/(1 + l) - (6 M r^4)/(1 + l) + (
           2 r^5)/(1 + l))))
```

```
\[Zeta][a_, b_, k_, l_, M_, r_] := 
 1/(2 a^2 (-b + 2 M - 2 r)) (-a Sqrt[1 + l]
      M (-4 a^2 + (4 r^2)/(
       1 + l)) + \[Sqrt](a^2 (1 + l) M^2 (-4 a^2 + (4 r^2)/(
          1 + l))^2 - 
       4 a^2 (-b + 2 M - 2 r) (a^4 b + a^4 k + a^2 b^2 k + a^4 b l + 
          a^4 k l + 2 a^4 M - 4 a^2 b k M + 2 a^4 l M + (a^6 k)/
          r^2 + (2 a^6 k l)/r^2 + (a^6 k l^2)/r^2 + (2 a^4 b k)/r + (
          2 a^4 b k l)/r - (4 a^4 k M)/r - (4 a^4 k l M)/r + 
          2 a^4 r + 2 a^2 b^2 r + 2 a^4 l r + 6 a^2 b r^2 - 
          a^2 k r^2 + (b^3 r^2)/(1 + l) - (b^2 k r^2)/(1 + l) - 
          4 a^2 M r^2 - (2 b^2 M r^2)/(1 + l) + (4 b k M r^2)/(1 + l) 
          + 4 a^2 r^3 + (4 b^2 r^3)/(1 + l) - (2 b k r^3)/(1 + l) - (
          8 b M r^3)/(1 + l) + (4 k M r^3)/(1 + l) + (5 b r^4)/(
          1 + l) - (k r^4)/(1 + l) - (6 M r^4)/(1 + l) + (2 r^5)/(
          1 + l))))
```

```
RV[a_, b_, k_, l_, \[Theta]_, M_, 
   r_] = \[Eta][a, b, k, l, M, r] + (a^2*(1 + l)*k/r)*
    Sin[\[Theta]]^2 - \[Zeta][a, b, k, l, M, r]^2*Cot[\[Theta]]^2 + 
   a^2*(1 + l)*Cos[\[Theta]]^2;
```

```
\[Alpha][a_, b_, k_, l_, \[Theta]_, M_, 
   r_] = -Sqrt[1 + l]*\[Zeta][a, b, k, l, M, 
     r]/(Sin[\[Theta]]*Sqrt[1 - (k/r)]);
```

```
\[Beta][a_, b_, k_, l_, \[Theta]_, M_, 
  r_] := (Sqrt[1 + l]/Sqrt[1 - (k/r)])*
  Sqrt[\[Eta][a, b, k, l, M, r] + (k/r)*
     a^2*(1 + l) - (\[Zeta][a, b, k, l, M, r])^2*(Cot[\[Theta]])^2 + 
    a^2*(1 + l)*(Cos[\[Theta]])^2]
```

```
re[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, 
  l_?NumericQ, \[Theta]_?NumericQ, M_?NumericQ] := 
 RankedMax[
  r /. NSolve[{RV[a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M, r] == 0, r > 0}, r, Reals],
   1]
```

```
pr[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, 
  l_?NumericQ, \[Theta]_?NumericQ, M_?NumericQ] := 
 RankedMax[
  r /. NSolve[{RV[a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M, r] == 0, r > 0}, r, Reals],
   2]
```

```
xc[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, 
  l_?NumericQ, \[Theta]_?NumericQ, M_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[\[Alpha][a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M, r]*\[Beta][a, b, k, 
     l, \[Theta], M, r]*
    D[\[Alpha][a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M, r], r], {r, 
    pr[a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M], re[a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M]}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 40, 
   Method -> {GlobalAdaptive, MaxErrorIncreases -> 10000}]/
  NIntegrate[\[Beta][a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M, r]*
    D[\[Alpha][a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M, r], r], {r, 
    pr[a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M], re[a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M]}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 40, 
   Method -> {GlobalAdaptive, MaxErrorIncreases -> 10000}]
```

```
R[a_, b_, k_, l_, \[Theta]_, M_, 
   r_] = (\[Alpha][a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M, r] - 
      xc[a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M])*
    D[\[Beta][a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M, r], r] - \[Beta][a, b, k, 
     l, \[Theta], M, r]*D[\[Alpha][a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M, r], r];
```

```
raverage[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, 
  l_?NumericQ, \[Theta]_?NumericQ, M_?NumericQ] := 
 Sqrt[(1/\[Pi])*
   NIntegrate[
    R[a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M, r], {r, re[a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M], 
     pr[a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M]}, MaxRecursion -> 40, 
    Method -> {GlobalAdaptive, MaxErrorIncreases -> 10000}]]
```

```
R1[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, 
   l_?NumericQ, \[Theta]_?NumericQ, M_?NumericQ, 
   r_] = ((Sqrt[(\[Alpha][a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M, r] - 
            xc[a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M])^2 + \[Beta][a, b, k, 
           l, \[Theta], M, r]^2] - 
       raverage[a, b, k, l, \[Theta], 
        M])^2)*(((\[Alpha][a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M, r] - 
          xc[a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M])*
        D[\[Beta][a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M, r], r] - \[Beta][a, b, k, 
         l, \[Theta], M, r]*
        D[\[Alpha][a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M, r], 
         r])/((\[Alpha][a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M, r] - 
          xc[a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M])^2 + \[Beta][a, b, k, 
         l, \[Theta], M, r]^2));
```

```
dc1[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, 
  l_?NumericQ, \[Theta]_?NumericQ, 
  M_?NumericQ] := (1/raverage[a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M])*
  Sqrt[(1/\[Pi])*
    NIntegrate[
     R1[a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M, r], {r, re[a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M], 
      pr[a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M]}, MaxRecursion -> 40, 
     Method -> {GlobalAdaptive, MaxErrorIncreases -> 10000}]]
```

```
In[109]:= n = 9;
```

```
(plotData = 
    Flatten[Table[{a, b, 
       ConditionalExpression[dc1[a, b, 0.2, 0, \[Pi]/2, 1], 
        Im[dc1[a, b, 0.2, 0, \[Pi]/2, 1]] == 0]}, {a, 1/1000, 
       5/10, (499/1000)/n}, {b, 1/1000, (50/100), (499/100)/n}], 
     1];) // AbsoluteTiming
```

```
During evaluation of In[109]:= NSolve::ztest: Unable to decide whether numeric quantities {-1658708289104552065399180903783896911730927000000000000000+<<18>>,-1658708289104552065399180903783896911730927000000000000000+<<18>>,<<18>>+13269666312836416523193447230271175293847416000000000000000 Root[{Plus[<<9>>]&,<<1>>&},{2,2}]^7 Root[<<1>>&,2,0]^7,<<1>>,1658708289104552065399180903783896911730927000000000000000+<<17>>,1658708289104552065399180903783896911730927000000000000000+<<17>>,<<18>>+(<<1>>) <<1>>+13269666312836416523193447230271175293847416000000000000000 Root[{Plus[<<9>>]&,Plus[<<36>>]&},{3,3}]^7 Root[-165787893495999994819128328250000000000+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]&,3,0]^7} are equal to zero. Assuming they are.
```

```
During evaluation of In[109]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
```

```
Out[110]= $Aborted
```

```
In[40]:= ListDensityPlot[plotData, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {a, b}), 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Here I am trying to calculate the average radius of a parametric curve by averaging the distance of points on the circumference of the curve from the center of the curve.The curve is parametrized by alpha and beta. If you do a parametric plot then you will get a closed curve very close to circle. Then the deviation from circularity is calculated by calculating root mean square of the deviation of the distance from the average radius.. Due to errors i aborted the execution but number of errors are more than what are shown.

Answer (score 3):

I did multiple changes to your code, which I summarize below, roughly from most important to least important.

1. For all instances of `NIntegrate` I switched to `Method->{"LocalAdaptive"}`. That is to say whenever there is something like  `NIntegrate[...,  Method -> {GlobalAdaptive, MaxErrorIncreases -> 10000}]]`, I used  `NIntegrate[...,  Method -> {"LocalAdaptive"}]]` instead.
2. Replaced all partial derivatives as follows: instead of, e.g., `D[\[Beta][a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M, r], r]` I used `(D[\[Beta][a, b, k, l, \[Theta], M, rr], rr] /. rr -> r)` and similarly for partial derivatives of `\[Alfa]`. This prevents the value of `r` for being set too early.
3. Increased `n` to 10 so `b` has two values instead of just one, otherwise the plot will be empty.
4. Switched exact integers to machine precision numbers, that is to say I replaced every exact integer (such as `1`, `2`, etc) with their machine precision counterparts (i.e. `1.`, `2.`, etc)
5. Called `Simplify` on the definitions of `\[Eta]` and `\[Zeta]` which managed to shorten them somewhat.

You should be able to easily implement these changes yourself. With the first two the `Table` should eventually finish but the plot will be empty because `b` has just one value. Third change takes care of that. The final two changes should not change the plot but I think they will speed up the code a bit.

The `Table` that makes your data took around 80 seconds to finish on my machine, and the result looks like this:

[image: Plot]

Comment: Please post modified lines

Comment: @Skj I added some clarifications to the answer. The instructions for modifying the code should be clear, so starting from the original code you posted in the question you can make the replacements yourself.